# The recordsource [query here] specified on this form or report does not exist

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

I got error in populating the result of my query to access form but it gives me "The recordsource [query here] specified on this form or report does not exist

Here is my code:

```
Me.RecordSource = "SELECT Division, Station, EmployeeNumber, BranchCode, AccountNumber, LedgerSetNumber, EmployeeName, EffectDate, TermDate, Amount, BillingType, DateBilled, PolicyNumber, BillingStatus, UpdateStatus, DateUpdated, SequenceNumber FROM DepEdTempBilling WHERE (UpdateStatus<>'Billed') ORDER BY Division, Station, EmployeeNumber, BranchCode, AccountNumber, LedgerSetNumber, EmployeeName"
```

screenshot:

[image]

Comment: `RecordSource` takes a String value (the SQL for the query)  Did you mean to use the `RecordSet` property ? Don't forget you need to use `Set` when assigning a value to that...

Comment: Sorry - I don't have any suggestions on that error.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is correct. For some reason that doesn't work. I did the same thing with my code. Here it is, hopefully this helps.

```
Me.RecordSource = "SELECT tblQuoteMaster.[Quote Number], tblQuoteMaster.Status, tblQuoteMaster.Prefix, tblQuoteMaster.[Rev Number], tblQuoteMaster.[AWC Rep], tblQuoteMaster.Estimator, tblQuoteMaster.Customer, CUSLST.Name1 AS Company, tblQuoteMaster.CustomerID, tblQuoteMaster.[Approx Value], tblQuoteMaster.Currency, tblQuoteMaster.Decription, tblQuoteMaster.[Date Received], tblQuoteMaster.[Date Sent], tblQuoteMaster.[Follow Up Date], tblQuoteMaster.[Contact for Quote], tblQuoteMaster.ProductCode FROM (tblQuoteMaster INNER JOIN CUSLST ON tblQuoteMaster.CustomerID = CUSLST.[Account Code]) INNER JOIN tblContact ON CUSLST.[Account Code] = tblContact.[Customer Number] WHERE (" & strSQL & ");"
```

I have seen some people assign their recordset to the RecordSource. That would always give me your error. For example:

```
Dim rcd As RecordSet
Set rcd = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT.....")
Me.RecordSource = rcd.Name
```

Answer (score -1):

Have re-made you table and form and tested, This error occurs when the Property Sheet (Access window not VBA editor) Form/Record Source: has “[query here]” in it clear this line out and try again, if that does not work try a clean new form with this statement. The command itself and SQL appear to be ok.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please try to make your answer more clear. I am not sure if it addresses the question.